# How do you translate this verse?

Tags: vulgata

I am reading John 1:27, and I'd like to know how do you make sense of *cuius* in this verse, and what does *corrigiam* mean?

> Ipse est qui post me venturus est, qui ante me factus est: cujus ego
>   non sum dignus ut solvam ejus corrigiam calceamenti.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Douay-Rheims (http://www.drbo.org/drl/chapter/50001.htm) has:

> The same is he that shall come after me, who is preferred before me: the latchet of whose shoe I am not worthy to loose.

Therefore "cujus ... corrigiam calceamenti" means "the latchet of whose shoe."

Cujus = 'whose' (Jesus's) and corrigiam = 'latchet' (object of solvam, 'I [may] loose[n]'). A latchet is a 'narrow leather strap, thong, or lace that fastens a shoe or sandal on the foot' (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latchet).

The extra 'ejus' is not translated in the DR. The second part literally says: "of whom I am not worthy to loose the latchet of his shoe / his shoe latchet," or "whose latchet of his shoe..." / "his latchet of whose shoe...": perhaps to emphasize that both the latchet and the shoe directly belong to Jesus.

Comment: As a note on *cuius/eius* (which look redundant), the Latin is closely following the original Greek: οὗ ἐγὼ οὐκ εἰμὶ ἄξιος ἵνα λύσω αὐτοῦ τὸν ἱμάντα τοῦ ὑποδήματος, where the genitive relative pronoun οὗ is pretty clearly going with ἄξιος "worthy". So *cuius* can be likewise taken with *dignus*, i.e. "I am not worthy of him, [not even] to loose..."

Comment: Thanks, that is also possible, or even preferable. "Dīgnus and indīgnus sometimes take the Genitive in colloquial usage and in poetry" (http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/ablative-specification).